# Passing value to a new form beetween two table using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a button to create a new record in other form which pass a certain value. In my problem, if you clicked create info button, it will open a new record for form_2 that pass ID value.

[image: a create info button which pass ID value to form_2]

I've tried several tips on internet like :

```
Private Sub CREATEINFO_Click()
Forms!Form_2.ID.Value = Forms!Form_1.ID.Value
End Sub
```

but i doesn't works.

Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `Forms!Form_2.ID.Value = Forms!Form_1.ID.Value`?

Comment: Is Form2 already open when you click "Create Info"? Or does the button open Form2?

Comment: the button open form2 and create new record.. is there any way to copy the form value to a variabel that i declare on vba?

Comment: AH, turns out you dont use the "!" and "." to declare a certain value from form you want to take. Thanks. I solved it.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered so it doesn't show up in the Unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

solved, it doesnt need the !, and to make the button run vba, i have to add a function.